# SpringBoot + Batch + Cloud Task @EnableTask annotation with single datasource causes "Sequence does not exist" Issue

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

Currently I'm using the SpringBoot ( 2.3.3 Version ) and Batch ( 4.2.4 Version )  and spring-cloud-starter-tsk ( 2.2.3 Version ) with Single Datasource ( oracle ). My BatchConfiguration extends the DefaultBatchConfigurer and made setDataSource. Now I'm trying to connect the Oracle DB and read records & generate the flatfile.

I'm getting below error and strange thing is I'm able to get the datasource and SEQUENCE (TASK_SEQ ) is available in DB.

[image]

Please find my other files below

- BatchConfiguraton.java is

[image]

- Application.java is
  [image]

-application.yml is
[image]

Comment: "SEQUENCE (TASK_SEQ ) is available in DB." - Oracle disagrees, and I (kind of) tend to trust it. Can you prove that it really exists in schema you're connecting to? What does `select * from user_sequences where upper(sequence_name) = 'TASK_SEQ';` return?

Comment: @Littlefoot : When I mentioned "SEQUENCE (TASK_SEQ ) is available in DB", i executed this manually. it doesn't mean Oracle supplied this. I'm following https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#metaDataSchema

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what "I executed this manually" means. What is "this"?

Comment: @Littlefoot: Spring Batch Tables and sequences can be executed manually/init process.. however, this detailed discuss not relevant to original post.

Comment: Your application connects to a database. In order to do that successfully, you have to provide valid credentials - username and password. User (identified by these credentials) should contain sequence whose name is TASK_SEQ. If it does not, you can't use it. Therefore: does that user own sequence named TASK_SEQ?

Comment: @Littlefoot: I'm able to connect the to datasource. i tried execute the user table query from configuration file. it worked. I can confirm that it's not Oracle issue anymore. it's something wrong from Spring Cloud Task/Batch Dependencies. We need not worry about database issues.

Comment: In that case, I hope someone else will be able to assist as I don't know Spring Batch. Good luck, by all means!

Answer (score 2):

In your batch configuration, you are using the `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` which creates a Map-based JobRepository in-memory. You need to remove this and use the JDBC based job repository pointing to your Oracle datasource as described in the reference documentation: [Configuring a JobRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobRepository).

You need to make sure that Spring Batch meta-data tables are created in your Oracle database before running your job.

The same configuration should be done for Spring Cloud Task as well.